# XCode Change Image From PopOver Navigation

Tags: xcode, ipad, popover

I'm wondering if you can help me.

Basically we have a set of 16 images,
ImageA.png
ImageB.png ect ect...
That need to be shown by selecting it from a "Menu".

I want it to work like a split view controller, but I don't want to limit the width of the screen by having the navigation bar at the side, as the app must run in Landscape mode.

Here is the screenshots of what I have come up with instead of the SplitView;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdy21.png

The image is in a UIImageView,
And I have added a PopOver to the button that is linked to the UITableView.

What I want, is to be able to select an image from the PopOver Navigation, and it will change the image in the UIImageView to the corresponding.

Sorry if I haven't explained myself enough... I'm new to XCode!

Also: I am using XCode in Storyboard mode;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSuyY.png

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: If it helps, it is possible to use a splitviewcontroller in landscape mode and not have the left side of the screen be constantly taken up by the master view

Comment: Yeah, That would work, but I can't figure out how to turn the splitviewcontroller navigation into a popover rather than a static bar at the side, It works in portrait mode, but not landscape.

Comment: Does it need to be a popover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the master view not be static on the side, implement this method in your `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```

return `YES` from this method, and the split view controller will behave the same way in landscape as it does in portrait